# non-singular matrix block matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $p$ be a prime number and $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ be nonsingular circulant matrices. How can I prove that this matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} A &B\\
B &C \end{bmatrix}$$ is nonsingular?

I have proved that $\det\begin{bmatrix} A &B\\
B &C \end{bmatrix}=\det(A)\det(C-BA^{-1}B)$. So the rest is to show that $\det(C-BA^{-1}B)\neq 0$ . Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You lack some assumption. We could just take $n=1, A=B=C=1$ with your current assumptions.

Comment: OK it should've been n>1 thx

Comment: This does not change the fact, that we can just choose $A=B=C$...